# Webview loading weburl show replaced images from one place to another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UIWebview to load a weburl, which contains few images and text. But after loading the url on webview images gets replaced with one another on some devices.
Is it problem with webpage?
My Code is here

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:_url];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

I have attach link to the actual loaded webview.

[this image actually appears to some other location but right now it gets loaded to this place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWc5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to [this](https://github.com/AdrianFlorian/AFImageViewer) one , it may help you..!!

https://github.com/AdrianFlorian/AFImageViewer

Images url are old, please replace with other like:

```
#image url: http://www.citi.io/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/1291-01-bruges-meteoweb.eu_.jpg

 -(NSArray *)imageUrls
    {
        return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://imgs.mi9.com/uploads/landscape/4717/free-the-seaside-landscape-of-maldives-wallpaper_422_84903.jpg"],
                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pics4.city-data.com/cpicc/cfiles42848.jpg"],
    nil];
    }
```

Comment: you didn't get my problem. its a webpage not urls of images. on safari it is loading correctly but on webview images changes their position.

Comment: hey Divya , please check autoresizing or constraints may some mistake, for checking give background color to webview.